# How to stop font-weight bold from making table wider

Tags: html, css

In this example, when you hover over `The longest name of all`, you'll see that the table's width extends.

Is there any way to stop this from happening **other than adding a width to the table** (in my unique situation I cannot use this).

I was hoping for a fix like `box-sizing: border-box` or something like that.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

tr:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Short name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The longest name of all</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: applying `overflow` then?